# ask init error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: cmd, alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I am trying to initialize the ask cli using ask init on my git bash command line but it keeps throwing an error

I tried adding credentials to my env variables

i am using windows so the steps are

```
npm install -g --production windows-build-tools
npm install -g ask-cli
ask init
```

expect to ask for creds
got:

```
This command will initialize the ASK CLI with a profile associated with your Amazon developer credentials.
------------------------- Step 1 of 2 : ASK CLI Initialization -------------------------
Switch to "Login with Amazon" page and sign-in with your Amazon developer credentials.
If your browser did not open the page, run the initialization process again with command "ask init --no-browser".
[Error]: Cannot obtain access token. Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Comment: You don't see a web browser launching a page? You need to login in the web browser, the command line waits for you to allow access to developer.amazon.com via the browser, when done the cli config resumes

Comment: i do it send me to the amazon developer website and i get the error message